# Passing an array argument to a bash script in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm trying to create a zsh alias that will run a bash environment file (called `environment` to set some environment variables) and then run a command `foo` in that environment, with the arguments that I used to invoke the alias. The problem is that sometimes I'll have an argument with spaces in them, and I haven't been able to figure out how to pass through correctly.

Here is an example of the alias, which I've tried:

```
foo() {
    set -x
    bash -c "source environment && foo $@"
}
```

When I call it like this:

```
foo launch --name "this is a test"
```

It doesn't pass through the `"this is a test"` argument correctly.

Here is the example output before the error:

```
bash -c 'source environment && foo launch' --name 'this is a test'
```

Comment: `bash -c 'source environment && sq launch-ec2' --name 'this is a test'` is putting `--name` into `$0`, and `this is a test` into `$1`... but the code `source environment && sq launch-ec2` doesn't look at `$0` or `$1` at all, so _of course_ they both get ignored!

Comment: BTW, if the things in the file `environment` should be aded _to the environment_, consider using the `-a` flag to make all subsequently-assigned variables automatically exported before sourcing it. `set -a` will turn that on, but you can just add it to the bash command line's flags: `bash -xac ...` or `bash -ac ...` if you don't want `-x` once you're done testing.

Comment: I'd also consider making it `source environment && exec foo "$@"` -- the `exec` means the copy of bash doesn't stay in memory after `foo` is started; and the copy of `foo` inherits the PID, so signals that would otherwise go to your shell instead go directly to `foo`.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally copy/pasted the wrong output (from `set -x`) at the end which made the question unclear. I've fixed it now - it should be `foo launch` rather than `sq launch-ec2`.

Comment: I believe my answer holds, even with that clarification.

Comment: ...or is the thing you're waiting to see in an answer an explanation of _why_ the described behavior happens? I'll admit that I jumped straight to "how to fix it" without any discussion of "why it happens".

Comment: ...as an example that should give you the information needed to work out "why it happens", consider the behavior of `set -- "first argument" "second argument" "third argument"; printf '<%s>\n' "prefix${@}suffix"`. If that isn't enough of a hint, let me know and I'll edit my answer to go into the details.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Your answer does seem to fix the problem. I think I understand how your answer works (although I don't fully understand why I need to include `"$0"` as an argument to `bash`). But I really don't understand why my original code didn't work. I'm sure it's because I misunderstand how quoting works, and that is very frustrating to me, since I've been using bash for years and can't get a good mental model of quoting. It would be great if you could point me to some resources that explained bash quoting comprehensively.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Understanding the `set --...suffix` example would require that I had a good understanding of `set` and `printf`, which unfortunately I don't, since I've never had to use them like that.

Comment: I've edited my answer with an explanation of the "why". For a longer discussion, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments is a good place to start, and has links to pages going into quoting and other topics specifically. https://stuff.lhunath.com/parser.png might also be worth a quick review just to make sure it aligns with your understanding.

Comment: ...really, you could put _any_ placeholder in the `$0` position; it's just that if you don't put _anything_ there, your next argument would become `$0` instead of `$1` and thus not be included in `"$@"` when the inner shell expands it. And using your original `$0` as the new `$0` is worthwhile because it leads to better error messages, in places where the shell uses `$0` as a prefix when printing errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why It Happens

When `"$@"` is expanded as part of a string, the preceding and following parts of that string are prepended to the first item in the `"$@"` list, and appended to the *last* item in that list.

So, when you run:

```
bash -c "source environment && foo $@"
```

...with `"$@"` containing the list `launch` `--name` `this is a test`, what you get is:

```
bash -c "source environment && foo launch" --name 'this is a test'
```

Only the `launch` -- the first array element -- becomes part of the `bash -c` argument that's parsed as source code; other members of the array then fill out `$0`, `$1` and so forth in the copy of bash that gets invoked. And because the code `source environment && foo launch` doesn't look at `$0`, `$1` or so forth, those arguments are subsequently ignored.

---

## How To Fix It

Use single-quotes around the string you want executed as literal code. Arguments should be kept out-of-band from that code. Thus, with newlines added for (a perhaps excessive amount of) visual clarity around where each argument begins and ends:

```
foo() {
  set -x
  bash \
    -xc \
    'source environment && foo "$@"' \
    "$0" \
    "$@"
}
```

Let's break down exactly what it's passing as its argument vector, when you call `foo "first argument" "second argument"` in zsh with the above function definition (assuming that this is being called from a script named `yourscriptname`, and filling out `$0` appropriately):

```
bash -xc 'source environment && foo "$@"' yourscriptname "first argument" "second argument"
```

...which, if we look at it as JSON-ish pseudocode, is an argument vector with the following contents:

```yaml
[
  "bash",                             # shell to run
  "-xc",                              # -x: enable tracing; -c: next argument is code
  "source environment && foo \"$@\"", # actual code to run
  "yourscriptname",                   # new $0 value when that code is running
  "first argument",                   # $1 value when that code is running
  "second argument"                   # $2 value when that code is running
]
```

That's exactly what we want. bash is running code that uses `"$@"` to expand to the argument list it was passed itself, and that argument list is kept out-of-band from the code that's being run so you don't have injection vulnerabilities.